# Find LDAP user in nested group through Java

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

Nothing I've found is working for me. And I'm having trouble finding answers that have valid code and aren't simply pasting a search filter string from another site.

The relevant code that's trying to do the search is:

```
SearchResult sr = executeSearchSingleResult(ctx, SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE, "dc=mydomain,dc=local", "(&(objectClass=person)(sAMAccountName=admin2))", new String[]{"memberOf"});
if (sr != null) {
    Attribute memberOf = sr.getAttributes().get("memberOf");
    if (memberOf != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < memberOf.size(); i++) {
            Attributes attributes = ctx.getAttributes(memberOf.get(i).toString(), new String[]{"CN"});
            Attribute attribute = attributes.get("CN");
            if (attribute != null) {
                log.info("member of : " + attribute.get(0));
            }
        }
        for (Enumeration e1 = memberOf.getAll(); e1.hasMoreElements();) {
            String unprocessedGroupDN = e1.nextElement().toString();
            String unprocessedGroupCN = getCN(unprocessedGroupDN);
            //checking something here
        }
    }
}

private static SearchResult executeSearchSingleResult(DirContext ctx, int searchScope, String searchBase, String searchFilter, String[] attributes) throws NamingException {
    NamingEnumeration result = executeSearch(ctx, searchScope, searchBase, searchFilter, attributes);
    SearchResult sr = null;
    try {
        while (result.hasMoreElements()) {
            sr = (SearchResult) result.next();
            break;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e, e);
    }
    return sr;
}

private static NamingEnumeration executeSearch(DirContext ctx, int searchScope, String searchBase, String searchFilter, String[] attributes) throws NamingException {
    SearchControls searchCtls = new SearchControls();
    if (attributes != null) {
        searchCtls.setReturningAttributes(attributes);
    }
    searchCtls.setSearchScope(searchScope);
    NamingEnumeration result = ctx.search(searchBase, searchFilter, searchCtls);
    return result;
}
```

This works fine when there are no nested groups. But say I have the following structure of groups and users:

```
My Admins (dn = CN=My Admins,CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=local)
    AdminUser1 (dn = CN=AdminUser 1,CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=local)
        AdminGroup1 (dn = CN=AdminGroup 1,CN=Users,DC=,mydomain,DC=local)
            AdminUser2 (dn = CN=AdminUser 2,CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=local)
```

This finds AdminUser1 just fine. It cannot find AdminUser2. What I need to do, is discover that AdminUser2 goes all the way back up to the highest level group called `My Admins`.

I found a lot of references to `1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941`, but different ways of putting that into the search filter have not helped.

What do I need to change in the code and/or the search filter to glean that a particular user at any particular depth of group nesting goes all the way back up to the topmost group?

Answer (score 1):

Using the [LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN) filter similar to:

`(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=(CN=UserName,CN=Users,DC=YOURDOMAIN,DC=NET))`

Will normally find all the groups that the user *CN=UserName,CN=Users,DC=YOURDOMAIN,DC=NET* is a member of.

But it is complicated.

- Microsoft Active Directory has several [group
  types](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Active%20Directory%20Groups)
- Microsoft Active Directory has different LDAP Services
  (normal and Global Catalog)
- Limitations

Any which may cause a group to not show within results.

So the groups MUST be [Security Groups](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Security%20Group) and you should use the [Global Catalog](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Global%20Catalog)

And then there are limitations. The LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN type searches tend to fail when groups are nested "too deep" or "Too Broad". That is too many nesting levels or too many groups that the member is a member of.

Comment: ....so what needs to change in the code, if anything? What should the search filter be? Or if not code, how does the AD structure change?

Comment: The Global Catalog (GC) that Jim mentions uses a different port (3268 for LDAP, 3269 for LDAPS). Use the search filter he gave you in his answer, together with the GC port. That should do the trick.

Comment: I changed to the filter above (assuming `UserName` means `sAMAccountName`, that which they type to log in) and the port to 3268 and it still fails to return anything. Both the users I'm trying (outlined above) are each a member of only 1 group. I've verified on the AD server that the groups are Security Groups.

Comment: "assuming UserName means sAMAccountName" -> The NO the CN=UserName,CN=Users,DC=YOURDOMAIN,DC=NET is the Fully Qualified Domain Name of the user.
See: https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Determining%20the%20FDN

Comment: only 1 group - is it a Local, Domain or Universal Group?

Comment: FDN didn't help either.

Comment: We must be missing something. Try using a KNOWN DAP Browser or a command line ldapsearch utility with the filter. (I like https://directory.apache.org/studio/)

Comment: Using Apache Directory Studio, I was able to determine that it doesn't like the set of parentheses around the FDN. It disabled the search button due to invalid syntax of the filter. Once I got rid of that, it did allow the search and it did return a list of two entries, each of which has a group (success). I made the same change in my Java code, although it only returns 1 result instead of 2. But at least it IS returning a result now, instead of nothing. So I can tweak it more from there.

Answer (score 0):

In LDAP we can query if a User belongs to a given group once you have established a connection you can query using either member or memberOf attribute.

Query for memberOf Attribute :
filter used : (&(Group Member Attribute=Group DN)(objectClass=Group Object class))
Ex : (&(memberOf=CN=group,ou=qa_ou,dc=ppma,dc=org)(objectClass=group))

Using member Attribute :
filter used : (&(Group Member Attribute=User DN)(objectClass=Group Object class))
Ex : (&(member=CN=user,ou=qa_ou,dc=ppma,dc=org)(objectClass=group))
But You'll have to search recursively using the member or memberOf attribute list for a user. e.g. if a user has the following group hierarchy :

cn: user1 memberOf: CN=group1,DC=foo,DC=example,DC=com memberOf: CN=group2,DC=foo,DC=example,DC=com

then you'll want to recursively lookup group1 and group2 with additional LDAP searches, and so on for groups which those groups are members of.

We can't use  LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN in production since it doesn't work when we have too deep nested hierarchy and it only works for Active Directory. Below Solution works independently with AD or OpenLDAP we just need to replace the group attributes.

Below is the sample code to query all the nested groups a User belongs to :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchControls;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchResult;

public class MemberDemo {
    private static final String contextFactory = "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory";
    private static final String connectionURL = "ldap://10.224.243.133:389";
    private static final String connectionName = "CN=administrator,CN=users,DC=ppma,DC=org";
    private static final String connectionPassword = "Conleyqa12345";

    public static int nestLevel = 3;
    public static int level = 1;

    // Optional
    private static final String authentication = null;
    private static final String protocol = null;
    private static String userBase = "OU=qa_OU,DC=ppma,DC=org";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();

        // Configure our directory context environment.

        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, contextFactory);
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, connectionURL);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, connectionName);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, connectionPassword);
        if (authentication != null)
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, authentication);
        if (protocol != null)
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, protocol);

        InitialDirContext context = new InitialDirContext(env);

        SearchControls constraints = new SearchControls();
        constraints.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

        Set<String> traversedGroups = new HashSet<String>();
        Set<String> relatedGroups = new HashSet<String>();
        List<String> tempParentColl = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<String>();
        List<String> tempGroups = new ArrayList<String>();

        String loginUser = "CN=qa20Nest,OU=qa_OU,DC=ppma,DC=org";

        String filter = "(&(member=" + loginUser + ")(objectClass=group))";
        tempGroups = findNestedGroups(tempGroups, context, filter, loginUser, constraints,
                tempParentColl, traversedGroups, getUserName(loginUser));
        relatedGroups.addAll(tempGroups);

        System.out.println("Parent Groups :");

        for (String group : relatedGroups) {
            System.out.println(group);
        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long elapsedTime = end - start;
        System.out.println("Total time taken in sec : " + elapsedTime / 1000);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public static List<String> findNestedGroups(List<String> tempGrpRelations, InitialDirContext context, String filter,
            String groupName, SearchControls constraints, List<String> tempParentColl, Set<String> traversedGrp,
            String groupIdentifier) {
        NamingEnumeration results;
        try {
            traversedGrp.add(groupName);
            results = context.search(userBase, filter, constraints);

            // Fail if no entries found
            if (results == null || !results.hasMore()) {
                System.out.println("No result found for :" + groupName);
                if (tempParentColl.isEmpty()) {
                    return tempGrpRelations;
                } else {
                    tempParentColl.remove(groupName);
                }
            }

            while (results.hasMore()) {
                SearchResult result = (SearchResult) results.next();
                System.out.println("DN - " + result.getNameInNamespace());
                tempParentColl.add(result.getNameInNamespace());
                tempGrpRelations.add(result.getNameInNamespace());
            }

            Iterator<String> itr = tempParentColl.iterator();
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                String groupDn = itr.next();
                String nfilter = "(&(member=" + groupDn + ")(objectClass=group))";
                tempParentColl.remove(groupDn);
                if (!traversedGrp.contains(groupDn)) {
                    findNestedGroups(tempGrpRelations, context, nfilter, groupDn, constraints, tempParentColl,
                            traversedGrp, getUserName(groupDn));
                }
            }

        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return tempGrpRelations;
    }

    public static String getUserName(String cnName) {

        String name = cnName.substring(cnName.indexOf("CN=")).split(",")[0].split("=")[1];
        return name;
    }
}
```